How do I give a NaT value a specified Date?
One of my datasets, I have to do a monthly analysis. On my december 2023 csv file, there is a datetime column. However,one date (December 8), is not on datetime format. Instead, for some reason, random integers and decimals just fill it. Take this for Example:



Datetime




07/12/2023 11:34 pm


07/12/2023 11:59 pm


35345345.543453



So I found a way to remove it.
I did the
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], datefirst=True, errors=coerce)
'
This will give me NaT Values. Now I just wantto convert ALL NaT Values to a datetime,(08/12/2023 12:00 am). It doesn't even have December 8. It can be December 9 at 1pm or December 15 at 4pm but it just needs to be a december date, with the dayfirst, because I am doing a monthly analysis.

Just fillna with the desired Timestamp:
df['Datetime'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
                    .fillna(pd.Timestamp('2023-12-08 12:00 am'))
                 )

Variant with to_datetime:
df['Datetime'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
                    .fillna(pd.to_datetime('08/12/2023 12:00 am', dayfirst=True))
                 )

Output:
             Datetime
0 2023-12-07 23:34:00
1 2023-12-07 23:59:00
2 2023-12-08 00:00:00

Note that this will fill all NaTs, whether originally a NaN or an invalid date. If you want to preserve NaNs and only fill the invalid dates you could use:
df['Datetime'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
                    .fillna(pd.to_datetime('08/12/2023 12:00 am', dayfirst=True))
                    .where(df['Datetime'].notna())
                 )

Example (as a new column for clarity):
              Datetime        Datetime_out
0  07/12/2023 11:34 pm 2023-12-07 23:34:00
1  07/12/2023 11:59 pm 2023-12-07 23:59:00
2      35345345.543453 2023-12-08 00:00:00
3                  NaN                 NaT


Thanks @ouroboros1 I wish dayfirst=True was the default in pandas
